# jQuery does not execute on dynamically loaded content, even on a click events

Tags: jquery, dom, toggle, document-ready

I have two `document.ready()` functions.  The first loads content into `div#header`. The second one performs a hide function and then a toggle function **on the newly loaded content**.  I am not sure if this is a queueing issue or something, but not even the `alert()` below is executed when I click the loaded content.  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#header").load("/documents/collegeradioheader.txt");
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hideme").hide(); 
    $(".slick-toggle").click(function() {
        alert('hi');
        $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('fast');       
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit: simplified code

Comment: you don't need two document. readys and if you want to have two you dont need two seperate script tags.

Answer (score 3):

Although the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) is a working solution, there is an `complete` event in the AJAX [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that fires when the load has finished.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#header").load("/documents/collegeradioheader.txt", function() {
        $(".hideme").hide(); 
        $(".slick-toggle").click(function() {
            alert('hi');
            $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('fast');       
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The click binding is probably happening before the `.load` is finished. Try replacing your `.click` with [a `.live` version](http://api.jquery.com/live):

```
$(".slick-toggle").live('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
    $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('fast');
});
```