# jqueryUI(Mobile) to ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

How to apply jQuery UI to the content loaded by AJAX.

I do load content using AJAX jQuery call which has a bunch of div tags and I want to style it when it loads. I am able to get the content but I am not able to style the content.

I am creating an app for mobile and I take an input on change event and load content based on the selected one. Then I append data to my container but the styles here are missed
 because for the mobile jquery appends the styles automatically after the page loads which is missed for the AJAX content.

Comment: What exactly do you want to style and what have you tried so far? Give us some code, clues, information, anything that is a little more helpful than a short description!

Comment: simply apply the styles of the content you want in your css and the will be applied to your div's as soon as the content is loaded.

Comment: @avikodak it works for me everytime, so proove me wrong

Comment: @EvilP jQuery Mobile initializes widgets using JS; it adds classes and changes the HTML structure of the widgets, so you have to either make jQuery Mobile initialize the widget(s) or add the jQuery Mobile specific classes and structure by yourself.

Comment: He Never wrote about mobile in the First Place and he edited the question Markup very much. !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it with this code:

```
$.mobile.activePage.page( "destroy" ).page();
```

Also if I have a list I use this:

```
$('ul.ui-listview').listview('refresh');
$.mobile.activePage.page( "destroy" ).page();
```

That will force jQuery to refresh all the elements and apply styles to them.

Edit: Updated code thanks to @Jasper

Comment: `$('.ui-page-active')` can be sped-up by using `$.mobile.activePage` instead. A reference to the current page is already created by jQuery Mobile, so there's no need to re-select the element.

Comment: Thanks, @Jasper. When I started with JqueryMobile that's what I found in the references. I'll update that..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you're trying to apply JavaScript on dynamically loaded content.

Check this thread for help [jQuery does not execute on dynamically loaded content, even on a click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954430/jquery-does-not-execute-on-dynamically-loaded-content-even-on-a-click-events) as it is discussing a problem similar to yours. Also check the jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function. Hope that helps!

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7 and `.delegate()` has been preferred since it was added to jQuery (1.4.2). I suggest not using `.live()` anymore since it will be removed from future versions of jQuery. jQuery 1.7+ uses `.on()` for `.bind()`/`.delegate()`/`.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `.trigger('create')`. Call it on the container when you replace it's content:

```
$('#container').html(newHTML).trigger('create');
```

Comment: Iam using a dynamic carousel in that .trigger('create') is not working properly

Comment: Its working for the drop down but it is not working for carouse